# ListView doesn't refresh on notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, listview, adapter

`ListView` doesn't seem to refresh when `notifyDataSetChanged();` is called, but does refresh when its adapter gets set again.

In my Activity `onCreate` I initialize my `ListView` and my adapter. Then I have this `Hanler` that checks for new values every second. `listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);` works but `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` doesn't do anything.

Here is the code:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                     lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,android.R.layout. simple_list_item_1, myIntegers);
            lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == DIS){
                    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(DIS, 1000);
                    if(!refresh()){
                        handler.removeMessages(DIS);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

   public boolean refresh(){

        if(ports.isEmpty()){
            return false;
        }else{
            listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); //WORKS
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // DOESN'T WORK
            return true;
            }
    }
```

So I was wondering how to make that work with `notifyDataSetChanged`, because I read that it is the right way to do it, and anyway even if the `setAdapter` does work it makes my listview jump to beginning every time it refreshes it.

EDIT:

To clarify things, I am adding more values to myIntegers.

Comment: can we see the code where you modify the existing adapter? Are you making changes to the adapter by calling its methods? or are you modifying the myIntegers data set?

Comment: im adding more values to myIntegers

Comment: Try instead adding the values using the adapter.add() method. I dont think you can modify the array that was used to create the adapter and then expect it to hold an updated instance to update the views from.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! Make an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try instead adding the values using the `adapter.add()` method. I dont think you can modify the array that was used to create the adapter and then expect it to hold an updated instance to update the views from.  Best of Luck!

Comment: It's confusing that `adapter.clear()` doesn't force the adapter to realize that the view should refresh, but `adapter.add()` or `adapter.addAll()` does. Thanks for the answer though!